# Intersection of open affines in a prevariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is an example of a prevariety in which the intersection of some two open affines is not an open affine? My examples of prevarieties that are not varieties does not extend beyond the affine line with the origin doubled. My guess is that the plane with four origins might give an example but I don't see how. Thanks.

Comment: I think this works. Take the plane with four origins. Then take two affine planes in that plane each with a different origin. Then their intersection is the affine plane without an origin which is not an affine variety.

Comment: Do you need more than two origins for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the plane with doubled origin is enough. From the construction you see two copies of $\mathbb{A}^2$ which intersect in a copy of $\mathbb{A}^2 - 0$.

Comment: If you take $X =$ Spec $K$, then the affine line with doubled origin in that case will satisfy that any intersection of open affines is affine.